# Count rows with same ID and Date <= CURDATE()

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write a SQL query with two SELECT statements combined?

I have this table

```
+-----+--------------+----------------+
| ID  |     DATE     | other props... |
+=====+==============+
|  1  |  2015-01-02  | 
+-----+--------------+
|  1  |  2015-02-03  |
+-----+--------------+
|  2  |  2015-03-16  | 
+-----+--------------+
|  3  |  2015-02-01  | 
+-----+--------------+
|  3  |  2016-05-14  | 
+-----+--------------+
```

and want to count

1. How many rows with the same ID exist
2. How many of that rows date <= current date

Example Result:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| ID  | COUNT | expired |
+=====+=================+
|  1  |   2   |    2    | 
+-----+-----------------+
|  2  |   1   |    0    |
+-----+-----------------+
|  3  |   2   |    1    |
+-----+-----------------+
```

I use these queries to achieve each of the tasks:

**count rows:**

```
SELECT `ID`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `ID`
```

**count expired:**

```
SELECT `ID`, COUNT(*) AS `expired` 
FROM `table`
WHERE `DATE` <= CURDATE(
GROUP BY `ID`
```

Comment: E.g. row with ID = 1 has two dates, which should be use for check expiration?

Comment: Both. E.g. the row with ID = 3 one date is expired the other one is ok so it should count 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt,
  SUM(`date`<CURDATE()) AS expired
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  ID
```

COUNT(*) will count all rows, while SUM() will count only expired rows (`date<CURDATE()` will be evaluated to 1 when the date is expired, and to 0 otherwise)

Please see a working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4370cc/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply count records and sum expirations:

```
SELECT
  id,
  count(*),
  sum(date < CURRENT_DATE())
FROM expiration
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer `JOIN`s on ranges for this kind of work:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count, COUNT(expire) AS expired
FROM Ex
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST('2015-02-15' AS DATE) AS expire) T
       ON T.expire >= date
GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15af23/5/0)</kbd>
...will produce the results you're looking for.  Obviously, substitute `CURRENT_DATE` or a parameter in the actual code; a specific value was used here to preserve the example results.

(In theory, range queries of this form can be answered via index scan/probe, rather than requiring a scan of the underlying table rows.  However, I'm not sure if MySQL is smart enough to take advantage of this, or maybe any RDBMS...)